# Getting tax price to calculate before submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm trying to get tax value in my checkout page to calculate once the state field is selected. I want to do this without having to submit a form as I want to display the tax rate on the page before the order is processed.

I am sure I will have to do this with Ajax and I have used Ajax a very limited amount of times. I know you send the request with Ajax to the php page and then Ajax pulls the field you need. So what I need to pull is, if Ohio is selected I need to pull the value of 1.065. If any other state is pulled I need to get the value of 1.

I have state variables listed in an array format like this because I am using this as the options for my state dropdown..

```
$taxvalue['Ohio'] = "Ohio";
$taxvalue['Virginia'] = "Virginia";
```

etc

Then I tried an if isset statement for when Ohio is selected to pull $taxed_state to get the value of 1.065. Else everything else is an untaxed_state.

```
$taxed_state = 1.065;
$untaxed_state = 1;

    if(isset($taxvalue['Ohio'])){
            $taxed_state;
       } else {
         $untaxed_state;
    }
```

This is how I am trying to configure the tax rate which I know will work once I can get the state to set before the form is submitted.

```
    $base_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];


            }
            $tax_price += $base_price * $taxed_state;
            $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;
}
```

I know this is the general way to send an Ajax call...

```
$.ajax({
url: "tax.php",
data: {
    action: ""
},
type: "POST",
dataType: "text"
}).fail(function(e, t, m) {
```

But I'm not sure how to structure this Ajax call to make this work for what I am trying to do. How can I go about doing this so I am getting the tax rate sent back one the State input field is selected.

I'm sure I'm pretty far off on this, but could anyone give some insight and point me in the right direction.

Update:

I'm putting in more code to see what it is I'm doing wrong..

```
$taxvalue['Wisconsin'] = 1;
$taxvalue['Wyoming'] = 1;

$taxed_state = 1.065;
$untaxed_state = 1;

    if(isset($taxvalue['Ohio'])){
            $taxed_state;
       } else {
         $untaxed_state;
    }

            $base_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];


            }
            $tax_price += $base_price * $taxed_state;
            $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;
}

 ?>
<div id="msgdiv" > </div>
                        <div class="ordersummarycontainer">
                                <span class="summarytitle"><p>Order Summary</p></span><br>
                                Items: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $base_price; ?></span>
                                <p>Shipping and handling: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $shipping_price; ?></span></p>
                                <p>Tax: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $tax_price - $base_price; ?></span></p>
```

At the bottom of my page I have the JS

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    var taxed_price = 0;

    $( "#taxvalue" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Ohio') {
            tax = 1.065;
        }
        else {
            tax = 1;
        }
        $('#taxed_price').val(base_total * taxed_state);
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Update:>

I commented out $taxed_state and untaxed_state because I had the values already in it, so I was trying to do it as you were.

```
$taxvalue['Wisconsin'] = 1;
$taxvalue['Wyoming'] = 1;

//$taxed_state = 1.065;
//$untaxed_state = 1;

    if(isset($taxvalue['Ohio'])){
            $taxed_state;
       } else {
         $untaxed_state;
    }

            $base_price = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $id => $product) {
                $product_id = $product['product_id'];
                $base_price += $products[$product_id]['price'] * $product['quantity'];
                $shipping_price += $products[$product_id]['shippingprice'] * $product['quantity'];


            }
            $tax_price += $base_price * $taxed_state;
            $total_price += $base_price + $shipping_price + $tax_price;
}
```

The area where the tax is echod to. Area where I am not getting anything to show up

```
<p>Tax: <span class="floatright"><?php echo "$" . $tax_price //- $base_price; ?></span></p>
```

Form where state drop down is...

```
<label for="state">State</label>
<select type="text" class="mediuminputbar preview" id="ShipTostate taxvalue" data-copy="#confirmstate" name="ShipTostate taxvalue" value="<?php echo escape($user->data()->state); ?>" required>
    <option value=''>Select a State</option>
    <?php
    foreach($taxvalue as $key => $val) {
        echo "<option value='$val'>$key</option>/n";
    }   
    ?>
    </select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    var taxed_state = 0;
    var base_total = 0;

    $( "#taxvalue" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Ohio') {
            taxed_state = 1.065;
        }
        else {
            taxed_state = 1;
        }
        $('#taxed_price').val(base_total * taxed_state);
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you might not even need to do an Ajax call. If you only have two tax rates (Ohio and non-taxed), then why not do it all through javascript? Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var tax = 0;

    $( "#state" ).change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Ohio') {
            tax = 1.065;
        }
        else {
            tax = 1;
        }
        $('#total').val(total * tax);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I updated my question to include the code I actually have.. I didn't add all of the variables for the states as that would be very redundant, but do you see what it is I'm not doing right? I'm getting nothing changing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax function on onchange event of the dropdown box.

Secondly, you might even not require ajax if you do not need anything at server-side (for example any database query). If the tax values are static and are not saved at database then you can do everything at clientside via javascript to instantly calculate tax rate.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I updated my question to include the code I actually have.. I didn't add all of the variables for the states as that would be very redundant, but do you see what it is I'm not doing right? I'm getting nothing changing

Comment: Make sure you are using the variable names correctly. As I can see you are not using tax variable when assigning the value. Also make sure your dropdown should contain similar values like "Ohio".

Comment: Correct, I am not assigning it to the taxvalue variables because those values carry the state names throughout the transaction.

Comment: here is the code running at jsfiddle, you can change the variable names accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/itsjawad/c4a9th5f/

Comment: I don't know why I can't get this to work. I updated my question again with what I have now. I think part of my issue is that I am not  good at mixing JS with PHP. I have a pretty good understanding of php but hardly any JS.

Comment: do you see what I am doing wrong? I have no idea why it won't work like your example.

Comment: Two things: first of all the id's you have given to html fields are not correct. Use exactly same id. Secondly, inspect the dropdown values.